# Solr Error This Indexschema is not mutable

Tags: solr, solrj

I want to use the schema.xml rather than the managed schema so I changed the following in the solrconfig.xml to the below

```
<schemaFactory class="ManagedIndexSchemaFactory">
    <bool name="mutable">true</bool>
    <str name="managedSchemaResourceName">managed-schema</str>
  </schemaFactory>
```

to

```
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
```

But I get  The indexschema is not mutable error when I try to Index a flat file using the post command.

Answer (score 75):

Remove the `AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory` section from the `updateRequestProcessorChain` config in your **solrconfig.xml**

The schemaFactory option in solrconfig.xml.
This controls whether the Schema should be defined as a "managed index schema": schema modification is only possible through the Schema API.
By default, if no schemaFactory is specified, then the default behavior is to use the `"ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"`

The ClassicIndexSchemaFactory requires the use of a schema.xml file,
which can be edited manually and is only loaded only when the collection is loaded. This setting disallows Schema API methods that modify the schema.

When ManagedIndexSchemaFactory is specified instead, Solr will load the schema from he resource named in `managedSchemaResourceName`, rather than
from schema.xml.

AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory : This processor will dynamically add fields to the schema if an input document contains one
or more fields that don't match any field or dynamic field in the schema.

read more on the same here
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.html

In short the above process factory is used for managed schema.
When one does not want to use ManagedIndexSchemaFactory it should be removed from the updateRequestProcessorChain.

For more details of it you can check out the solr code or read the source code of the `AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java`
Debug the method `processAdd(AddUpdateCommand cm)` , will help more on the same.

With the updated version of  **`Solr 7.2`** you need to the `update.autoCreateFields` to `false` in the `updateRequestProcessorChain` definition in `solrconfig.xml`.

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" default="${update.autoCreateFields:false}"
                             processor="uuid,remove-blank,field-name-mutating,parse-boolean,parse-long,parse-double,parse-date,add-schema-fields">
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer, this worked great for me.  Can you elaborate as to why this needs done?

Comment: Worked for me too. Why ins't this selected as the answer?

Comment: I really don't know why he hasn't yet accepted this as an answer :(...Even though it helped many .

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti +1. Would you mind expanding on what or how these items solve this problem?

Comment: Any way to find out what field is failing to match too? Because I thought that all my fields existed. Such a bummer not logging this in the adminUI. :(

Answer (score 13):

At least in Solr 7.2 you should probably just switch **update.autoCreateFields** to **false** in the updateRequestProcessorChain definition in **solrconfig.xml** as the comment indicates.

```
<!-- The update.autoCreateFields property can be turned to false to disable schemaless mode -->
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" default="${update.autoCreateFields:false}"
                             processor="uuid,remove-blank,field-name-mutating,parse-boolean,parse-long,parse-double,parse-date,add-schema-fields">
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

That worked for and now I'm only getting pretty error messages like

> Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: ERROR: [doc=urn:nbn:cz:tst01-000001] unknown field 'title'

as I'm tuning my static, unmanaged schema in **schema.xml**.

Comment: works for `Solr 9.0.0` too

Answer (score 4):

Update `autoCreateFields` to false in solrconfig.xml.

`${update.autoCreateFields:false}`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this instead of editing your `solrconfig.xml` file is to add the `update.autoCreateFields=false` value to your `core.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

For SOLR 7.7.2

Remove 'add-schema-field' from the updateRequestProcessorChain.

```xml
  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" default="${update.autoCreateFields:true}"
                               processor="uuid,remove-blank,field-name-mutating,parse-boolean,parse-long,parse-double,parse-date">
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Answer (score -2):

I realize this post is old but I ran into the same behavior today when importing a json file. The issue was the .json was not properly formed. It was missing the [] (square brackets) at the top and bottom of the file and the ',' (commas) between the objects.  I validated the file using http://jslint.com/. The error was resolved once i made these changes.

NOTE: These were the issues which kept my file from being properly formed. I would suggest that you run your data through some type of validator to rule out whatever issue(s) your file MAY be having.

I hope this helps.